# What happens on setting replication factor to 0

Tags: hadoop

In a multi node cluster Can we set hadoop  block replication factor to 0?

Is that possible? If it is possible then What will happen?

Also What will happen if we set hadoop block replication factor to 0 in single  Pseudo mode cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both Single and Multi node confgurations, you cannot set the replication factor of a file to zero. The execution will fail with the below error.

```
replication must be >= 1
```

**When we get this error :**

For changing the replication factor of a file in HDFS, we need to use the command `hadoop fs -setrep <rep_factor> path`, If you use 0 as replication factor in the previous command you will get this error. You cannot use configuration xml file for changing the replication factor of a file which is in HDFS, Value of `dfs.replication` in the client configuration xml file will be used in case of copying files to HDFS.

Even if you specify dfs.replication as 0 in the client configuration or the command itself (as `hadoop fs -Ddfs.replication=0 -put testfile.txt /` ) while copying files to HDFS, the command will fail, But you will a weird message as follows

```
put: file /testfile.txt._COPYING_ on client X.X.X.X
```

Comment: Ok. When do we get error?At the time of changing  the respective property in conf xml? or at the time of loading a file in HDFS using hadoop dfs -put command?